# How to hide xattr lines from "ls -l" output

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, bash

When I list files in the command line with "ls -l",  I get all the xattr lines also and this clutters the output, making it hard to find the files I want.  How can I list a directory without printing the xattr lines?

Here's an example of what I get when I type "ls -l"

```
drwxrwxr-x@ 461 root    admin  -   15K Aug 31 19:54 bin/
    com.apple.metadata:_kTimeMachineNewestSnapshot    50B 
    com.apple.metadata:_kTimeMachineOldestSnapshot    50B 
drwxr-xr-x@  13 walter  admin  -  442B Jul 18 08:56 etc/
    com.apple.metadata:_kTimeMachineNewestSnapshot    50B 
    com.apple.metadata:_kTimeMachineOldestSnapshot    50B
```

**Edit:**
I figured it out. See answer below.

Comment: Please don't answer your question inline. Instead cut out the answer part and add new answer below!

Answer (score 1):

The `~/.bashrc` file had an alias that made that the default. I removed the alias and the extra lines were gone.

The line in my `.bashrc` file read: `alias ls='ls -FGhO@`.

Remove the "@" and problem is solved.